# Can't call a function from class tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class Video:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v1 = StringVar()    
        self.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=v1)
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.downloadUrl = v1.get()
    def downloadVideo(self):

        ydl_opts = {}
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                self.ydl.download([self.downloadUrl])
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)    
menuOne = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label='Magrobebi', menu=menuOne)   
menuOne.add_command(label='Download Video', command=Video.downloadVideo)
```

I'm trying to create a button in the menu that will download a video. I've been having trouble passing around that downloadUrl since it's not a global variable.
I can't put the command itself in the class cause it won't even get created that way. Currently, "TypeError: downloadVideo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" is the error I've been having, I can't call a function from another class in this, how do I get around this? I just want to have a button that creates an entry where the user can input a link and download it.

Comment: Your downloadVideo method isn't static. You either have to make it static (@staticmethod above the method) or instantiate an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If referencing to `self` is an issue, you can add the code outside of the class, for example:

```
from tkinter import *
import youtube_dl

root = Tk()

v1 = StringVar()    
entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=v1)
entry1.pack()

def downloadVideo():
    downloadUrl = v1.get()
    ydl_opts = {}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download(downloadUrl)

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)    
menuOne = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label='Magrobebi', menu=menuOne)   
menuOne.add_command(label='Download Video', command=downloadVideo)

root.mainloop()
```

This produces a window with a button which when pressed, gives an option to download the video, and under that, an entry box.

EDIT: The `downloadUrl = v1.get()` needed to be in the call to `downloadVideo()` as `.get()` retrieves the string inside the `StringVar()` immediately.

Comment: Okay I did it like that, though the problem right now seems to be that it can't read what's in the entry properly, considering it gives an error "ERROR: '' is not a valid URL.", how can I work around this?

Comment: @Niko I edited the answer, the `get()` method needed to be called just before the request for the video.

Answer (score 0):

Since `downloadVideo` is a method on `Video`, you simply need to create an instance of `Video` and then use it to call the function. This has nothing to do with tkinter, this is simply how python classes work.

For example:

```
video = Video()
menuOne.add_command(..., command=video.downloadVideo)
```

However, you have another bug in `Video` where you do this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.v1 = StringVar()    
    self.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=v1)
    self.entry1.pack()
    self.downloadUrl = v1.get()
```

You are setting `self.downloadUrl` about 1 millisecond after creating `self.v1` so it will always be the empty string. Instead, you need to call `v1.get()` at the time that you actually need the value, which is inside of `downloadVideo`:

```
def downloadVideo(self):
    ydl_opts = {}
    url = self.v1.get()
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            self.ydl.download([url])
```